# Why the attachments don't change weapon stats in Dead Space 3?

Tags: dead-space-3

*Not a single attachment* aside from the "full zoom scope" has any effect on the displayed stats for my weapons in the both categories:

[image: full zoom scope]

[image: damage support]

[[image: ammo support[2]]

Have I simply maxed out the displayed values? [It's known that the weapons can be improved beyond the statistics bar](https://old.reddit.com/r/DeadSpace/comments/18ui1m/can_your_dead_space_3_weapons_exceed_the_stat_bar/) (upper and lower tool), but I haven't reached the end of any meter as seen in the screenshots.